# Does laravel home route need to be at the bottom?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I'm new to laravel and trying out routes.

At the moment I have 2 routes:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');

Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
```

These routes both work now. But before I had home route above users. That caused an 404 (controller method not found exception) on users.

Am I supposed to have home route at the bottom or am I doing something wrong?

I don't want to get in trouble later in the project ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first mapping route for the url will be choosen.
If you write the HomeController-line first, following will happen:
For the url .../users, the / will map for the Home route and laravell will try to call the method users in the Homecontroller.

Comment: Thanks you, this explains it perfectly :D